# Handling duplicate primary key conflicts in Multi leader replication with multi data center operation

Tags: oracle, system-design

I have two data centers, each data center is configured as Single leader, multiple follower node configuration. So there are two leaders, one in each data center. Both of them can accept write requests. Write that happens on leader of one data center is replicated on leader  node of other data center in async way.

Now, Let's say I have a Oracle table transaction_logs, where is tran_id as the primary key.
I cannot keep this tran_id as auto increment, because if the leader node in each data center gets write request at the same time, then same value of primary key will be used for two different write request and during data replication from leader of one data center to other data center, write conflict will occur due to duplicate primary key.

So, How should we design the primary key in such use case. Requirement is application or system should generate the primary key value, data type should be optimal as index will be created on the primary key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

- Generate IDs by Sequence
- Sequence has increment of 10
- Each datacenter has unique "id" which is also starting value of sequence. So in DC generates ID(1,11,21,...) and other DC generates ID(2,12,22,...).
- If you want only to write onto leader database you can set datacenter id as session context "global" variable. So ID generating trigger can add it to a number generated by SEQUENCE.
- Each table has artificial columns managed by triggers(creation_dc, last_updated_dc, creation_timestamp, last_update_timestamp)

Logical replication tools like Shareplex/GoldenGate can be instructed to use higher timestamp value to resolve collision when it is detected.

This way you can even handle multi-writer architecture.